# Отслеживание onStart/onResume других приложений (можно с root)

Tags: android, root

Фоновый сервис должен отслеживать события onStart/onResume для всех приложений и, соответственно, выполнять определенные действия.

В некоторых приложениях по таймеру отслеживается верхняя Activity в списке Activity, но это довольно неплохо грузит процессор (по крайней мере на слабых девайсах).

Должен же быть иной способ? Если способ требует Root, он тоже подойдет.
Ссылки, мануалы и прочее приветствуется.